# Convert from one timezone to another taking into consideration daylight saving

Tags: c#, timezone, dst

I want to convert a datetime from one time zone to another. For this i need to pass the zone id to the method FindSystemTimeZoneById. But i do not have this information and need to determine that by using a switch-case.
Here i also need to take into account daylight saving. but in order to determine whether a time is in DST i need that zone id beforehand.
Is there any way to determine whether a time is in DST without the zone id. My server is in zone 1 and i want to convert the time to zone 2.

Here is the snippet:

```
public DateTime ConvertToDestTime(DateTime currentTime, string sourceTimeZoneUtc, string serverTimeZoneUtc)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(ReturnTimeZoneString(sourceTimeZoneUtc));
        TimeZoneInfo serverTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(ReturnTimeZoneString(serverTimeZoneUtc));
        DateTime serverTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentTime, sourceTimeZone, serverTimeZone);
        return serverTime;
    }

    private string ReturnTimeZone(string utcOffset)
    {
        string timezone = string.Empty;
        string isDaylight = //need to determine whether time is in DST here

        if (isDaylight == "N")
        {
            switch (utcOffset)
            {
                case "-04:00":
                    timezone = "Atlantic Standard Time";
                    break;
                case "-05:00":
                    timezone = "Eastern Standard Time";
                    break;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (utcOffset)
            {
                case "-04:00":
                    timezone = "Eastern Standard Time"; 
                    break;
                case "-05:00":
                    timezone = "Central America Standard Time";
                    break;                    
            }
        }

        return timezone;
```

Comment: Check out Jon Skeet's [Nodatime](http://nodatime.org/), and stop worrying about it :) The default date-support is *good-enough* for most applications, but once you start crossing time-zones it can be a little bit more tricky.

Comment: What kind of value do you have in `currentTime`? (What does its `Kind` property return?)

Comment: It is coming as "Unspecified". This field has a value like "7/13/2014 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: Then TimeZoneInfo should just handle the DST for you. Specifying a time zonr as a UTC offset is generally a very bad idea though.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the source time to UTC time.

```
string sourceTimeZone="Atlantic Standard Time;
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(sourceTimeZone);
DateTime sourceUTCTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(currentTime, timeZoneInfo);
```

then using the converted UTC time get the destination time as below,

```
string destinationTimeZone="India Standard Time";
TimeZoneInfo destTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(destinationTimeZone);
DateTime destinationUTCTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(sourceUTCTime, destTimeZoneInfo);
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check ou t Microsoft's "timeless" article [Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx).

The article may be a few years old, but the priciples and problem scenarios are still today's topics.

There is a dedicated chapter about [Dealing with Daylight Savings Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx#datetime_topic6).

> By converting your **local** time views to **universal time** prior to
>   performing your calculations, you get past the issues of time
>   accuracy.

So, convert your local time to UTC format first and then into the target time format.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform this type of reverse mapping reliably.  There are just two many possible time zones that any particular offset could fall into.

- See "TimeZone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- See also [all the places that `-04:00` might be used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9204:00).
- Lastly, recognize that because each time zone in North America falls-back in their own local time, some values are shared by two time zones at once.

  For example, `2014-11-02T01:00:00-05:00` could belong to *either* US Central Time (CDT) or US Eastern Time (EST), [as shown here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20141102T01&p1=64&p2=179).

Answer (score 0):

A bit old question, but may be somebody will enjoy bellow extension

```
    public static class DateTimeExtension
    {
        public static DateTime ConvertBetweenTimeZones(this DateTime d, string sourceTimeZone, string destinationTimeZone)
        {
            var tziSource = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(sourceTimeZone);
            var tziDestination = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(destinationTimeZone);

            var utcDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(d, tziSource);

            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDate, tziDestination);
        }
    }
```

And some unit test for that:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class DateTimeTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ConvertBetweenTimeZonesTest()
        {
            var dateTime = new DateTime(2023, 1, 27, 21, 0, 0);

            var sourceTimeZone = "Central European Standard Time";
            var destTimeZone = "UTC-02";

            var dateResult = dateTime.ConvertBetweenTimeZones(sourceTimeZone, destTimeZone);
            
            var expectedDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 27, 18, 0, 0);
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedDate, dateResult);
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class TimeZoneInfoTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ConvertBetweenTimeZonesTest()
        {
            var timeZone = "Central European Standard Time";
            var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
            
            Assert.AreEqual("UTC+01:00", tzi.GetShortName());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jarek, there is missing method in your solution:

```
public static String GetShortName(this TimeZoneInfo info)
{
    return info.DisplayName.Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0];
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35061015)