# Parsing date string while specifying the time zone

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I am working with .NET, and I am running into issues with time zones. I have separate date and time components, both as strings. I want to parse the string as Eastern Prevailing Time (EPT). However, my system is using the UTC clock, so I cannot assume it to be the local time while parsing.

What's the way to go about this? Is there a library that can come in handy?

Currently, I am doing the following:

```cs
const string DateFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
const string TimeFormat = "HH:mm:ss";

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date_string, DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateOnly))
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(time_string, TimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var timeOnly))
    {
        return dateOnly.Date + timeOnly.TimeOfDay;
    }
    return dateOnly.Date;
}
```

The current implementation parses the `DateTime` values as UTC, but we know that these are in EPT. If I were to convert the parsed `DateTime` to EPT, then the actual time would change along with the time zone. Changing the offset manually doesn't help either, since it does not take into account daylights savings.

Comment: What does your input date string look like.  If it has a timezone in the string it will correctly get parse correctly.  If input doesn't have a timezone than you need to modify the culture (IformatProvider) to be EPT.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-7.0

Comment: Use DateTimeOffset with TimeZoneInfo to generate your date/time object. You may have to specify the kind depending on the string.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783489/convert-from-one-timezone-to-another-taking-into-consideration-daylight-saving

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75986962/convert-date-and-time-to-another-based-on-timezone

Comment: The code provided does _not_ parse the values as UTC.  It parses them into a `DateTime` whose `.Kind` property is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  There is no time zone assigned.  You would need to show conversion to `DateTimeOffset` or to a different `DateTime` using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` or similar function.  Also, without inputs and desired outputs, your question is not clear.